# Problema con el alerta para guardar contraseñas de google

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un sitio desarrollado en ASP .NET MVC. En un formulario de registro, entre otros campos, tengo un campo teléfono y debajo la contraseña y la confirmación de la contraseña. Al rellenar estos 3 campos, utilizando el navegador Google Chrome, el navegador me pregunta si quiero guardar la contraseña para ese sitio. Si coloco que sí, la próxima vez que ingreso a este formulario, el campo teléfono y el campo contraseña me aparecen completos con los datos recordados.

Se que puedo evitar esto utilizando el atributo HTML 'autocomplete', pero por qué el navegador asume que el campo teléfono es un campo usuario? Simplemente porque aparece arriba de la cntraseña? Hay forma de evitar esto o que directamente, el navegador no me haga la pregunta en ese formulario?

El código correspondiente a esos tres campos es el siguiente:

```
    @*Telefono*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefono, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefono, new { @placeholder = "0(341)611-2233", @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off", @id = "telefono" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="email" hidden="hidden" />
    <input type="password" hidden="hidden" />

    @*Contraseña*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @placeholder = "Contraseña", @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*Confirmar contraseña*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @placeholder = "Confirmar contraseña", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: dentro de tu vista, estas usando la etiqueta <form> ?

Comment: @ArielIgnacio así es. Inclusive probé colocando el atributo 'autocomplete=off' a la etiqueta form. Esta etiqueta la estoy declarando usando razor (@Html.BeginForm...)